# Multiple, nearly congruent Tables or single Table in MSSQL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design, sql-server-2012

What's your advice to solve at MSSQL 2012?
And makes MSSQL 2008 R2 any difference in this case?

---

Solution 1

Create multiple nearly congruent tables in this shape:

```
TextTable1(ID:int, text1:varchar(200))

TextTable2(ID:int, text1:varchar(200), text2:varchar(200))

TextTable3(ID:int, text1:varchar(200), text2:varchar(200))

TextTable4(ID:int, text1:varchar(200), text2:varchar(200), text3:varchar(200))
```

For all tables ID is PrimaryKey.

---

Solution 2

Create single table in this shape:

```
TextTable(ID:int, context:varchar(50), text1:varchar(200), text2:varchar(200), text3:varchar(200))
```

With PrimaryKey(ID, context).

Comment: If `text1`, `text2` and `text3`'s values are essentially interchangeable, then they should be a *single* column, with multiple *rows* containing the data.

Comment: @bvr context is just a name of the old table, because we didn't want to stay with the old ID's

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever with 'essentially interchangeable' you mean if text1 could be stored in text2 without problems?

Comment: If they fulfill the same role - e.g. asking questions here, you can apply up to five tags. Those five tags (however they're encoded) ought to be stored as up to five rows in a table somewhere, in the same column - so that querying by tag is straightforward. If tag order matters, that ought to be stored as a separate column, but it would still be five rows with the order available for queries, rather than the order being encoded in column names.

Comment: Okay thanks for help, Solution 2 will be the way